# Metro Circle Button Background

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button

I am using `Button` with `MetroCircleButtonStyle` with `MetroUI` in WPF. How can I change the background of this `Button`?

Code:

```
<Button Background="Green" 
        Name="button2"
        Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}" 
        Width="50" Height="50" />
```

Currently the button look like this but i want the one on the right:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you get the [Git-Source](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro) for [MahApps.Metro](http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/), It has a few demo targets that show you the normal usage of almost all their controls.

In `MetroDemo` target under `MainWindow.xaml` their usage of `MetroCircleButtonStyle` looks like:

```
<Button Width="55"
        Height="55"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}">
  <Rectangle Width="20"
              Height="20">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
      <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill"
                    Visual="{StaticResource appbar_city}" />
    </Rectangle.Fill>
  </Rectangle>

</Button>
```

In your case, you'd prolly want the "appbar_add" resource

```
<Button Width="55"
        Height="55"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}">
  <Rectangle Width="20"
              Height="20">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
      <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill"
                    Visual="{StaticResource appbar_add}" />
    </Rectangle.Fill>
  </Rectangle>
</Button>
```

Note you need to add the `ResourceDictionary` containing the `Canvas`'s for this. It can also be got from NuGet Packages ([MahApps.Metro.Resources](http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/#resources)).

Concept is pretty much apply the `Canvas` path of your choosing(which you get quite a few of as listed in the docs) as the `VisualBrush` and you should be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to design your own custom button but it's pretty easy.

[Here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0470__Windows-Presentation-Foundation/ButtonwithImagesource.htm) are explained plenty of ways you can do that.